# ReactJs - Infinite scroll from bottom to top not fetching new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a chat screen on my app that will initially display messages at the bottom of a div, and as a user scrolls up, more messages will be fetched. I am using the `react-infinite-scroll-component` package to handle the infinite scrolling.

To illustrate this issue, I created and edited an example from online, using simple divs to replicate chat messages.

The code below should fetch some data(dummy data in this example), after a user scrolls up the div. However instead, no data is being fetched as a user scrolls up, and **only the original data(the initial state) is being displayed.**

**Here is the code snippet:**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const style = {
  height: 30,
  border: "1px solid green",
  margin: 6,
  padding: 8
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: Array.from({ length: 20 })
  };

  fetchMoreData = () => {

    console.log('Fetch called')


      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(Array.from({ length: 30 }))
      });
   }


  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="scrollableDiv"
        style={{
          height: 300,
          overflow: "auto",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column-reverse"
        }}
      >
        {/*Put the scroll bar always on the bottom*/}
        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={this.state.items.length}
          next={this.fetchMoreData}
          style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column-reverse" }} //To put endMessage and loader to the top.
          inverse={true} //
          hasMore={true}
          loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
          scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
        >
          {this.state.items.map((_, index) => (
            <div style={style} key={index}>
              div - #{index}
            </div>
          ))}
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the place where I got the code from: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-pond-6l6x5y?file=/src/index.js

In the example, once the user reaches the top of the container, fetch is not being called. However I would like it so that when the user has scrolled to the top of the div, fetch is called.

Currently, only the last item of the initial state is displayed at the top of the container. I would like the user to be able to continue to scroll, and subsequently, the fetch method will be called.

Also note that the **console.log('Fetch called')** within `fetchMoreData`is never being logged to the console. Is there anything missing from the code that could be causing this issue?

Comment: The direction you set is the opposite, and it will only trigger if you scroll up.

Comment: @SkyClong, yes it should trigger if you scroll up, however as I mentioned, the function isn't trigged even when I scroll up the div/container

Comment: @SkyClong After I reach the top of the `div` (when I reach the last item of the initial state), I can no longer scroll up anymore, although It should call the fetch method.

Comment: Scroll to top will trigger!

Comment: @SkyClong I am scrolling up and it's not triggering, it just reaches the end/top of the div. How can I make it so users can scroll up further to trigger?

Comment: what's your react-infinite-scroll-component version ?

Comment: @SkyClong The version is 4.1.0

Comment: change to 6.1.0, like this https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-cookies-qn3qw3?file=/src/index.js.

Comment: @SkyClong Please check my original post. I have added a link to the place where the example is from. The issue persists with their example. Once the top of the div is reached, fetch is not being called. This is what I would like to implement. Any ideas how I could implement this?

Comment: glad to help u !

Answer (score 0):

How about check react version.
I guess you copied [this sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/w3w89k7x8?file=/package.json:126-149) and tried.

Comment: this is the sample I tried: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-pond-6l6x5y?file=/src/index.js My aim is to load the next batch of data(call fetch method) when the user has scrolled to the top of the container, however even in the example, new data isn't loaded when the top of the container is reached. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: I've used this code in the latest version of react(locally), and the same thing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. The hasMore value should be regulated or the fetchMoreData function will be called indefinitely.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-fire-62xhpj?file=/src/index.js